# У поля input с номером карты пропадает фокус и при вводе цифры переставляются местами

Tags: javascript, jquery

На некоторых мобильных устройствах (sony) у поля input с номером карты пропадает фокус.

```
$("#cardNumber").mask("9999 9999 9999 9999?999");
```

Из-за этого приходится каждый раз менять раскладку с текстового ввода на цифровой (при каждом вводе).

На Sony ZR, Android 5.1.1. при вводе номера карты цифры переставляются местами

Можете хотя бы подсказать в каком направлении искать?

Поиск ответа, не дал результатов, но не исключаю вероятности, что не правильно ищу.

Рабочий пример [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/vkfarha6/8/).

Хочется хотя бы глобально понять почему это это происходит и что на это влияет.

**UPD 1.0**

Для полей используется плагин [maskedinput](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/yk5p69zk/)

Эта часть кода отвечает за инпут, в котором `input.caret()` ведет себя не корректно.

```
function androidInputEvent() {
 var curVal = input.val(), pos = input.caret();

 if (oldVal && oldVal.length && oldVal.length > curVal.length) {
  console.log(oldVal);
  for (checkVal(!0); pos.begin > 0 && !tests[pos.begin - 1]; ) pos.begin--;
  if (0 === pos.begin) for (;pos.begin < firstNonMaskPos && !tests[pos.begin]; ) pos.begin++;
  input.caret(pos.begin, pos.begin);
 } else {
  for (checkVal(!0); pos.begin < len && !tests[pos.begin]; ) pos.begin++;
  input.caret(pos.begin, pos.begin);
 }
 tryFireCompleted();
}
```

В чем тут может быть причина?

Comment: Я не знаю как работает это расширение на $.mask(), но подозреваю, что оно срабатывает типа как onkeyup или onchange.

Т. е. каждое изменение проверяет новый ввод. Если введённое правильно — подставляет это же значение $input.val(getVal).

Если это верно, то каждый раз подставляя новое значение (пусть и правильное) каретка встаёт туда, куда ей следует (в конец, вроде). А у телефона вовсе фокус пропадает.

Попробуйте реализовать маску ввода иначе.

Для примера, попробуйте в https://jsfiddle.net/higimo/etqtcvc6/ нажать кнопку home, когда что-то напишите.

Comment: как иначе? чем этот способ плох?

Comment: Например, тем, что не надо перезаписывать, значение инпута, если оно правильное. И вообще, лучше проверять правильность когда попытались отправить.

Comment: спасибо за коммент, немного прояснилось

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number">
```

Только может быть велика вероятность что не все браузеры поддерживают